# Should i connect two Android phones directly using Sockets

Tags: android, sockets, communication, android-wifi

I want to make a communication between two Android phones directly on WIFI. These two Android phones are not in the same network. I have gone through this post
[Incorporating Socket Programming into your Applications : Android](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

I assume that we can connect two Android phones using socket.  But i dont know what are possible limitations for direct sockets.
Will it work no matter where the two devices are and what are their IP addresses ?
Does Android allow for incoming connection if i make it a Server ?
Is it a good idea to connect two phones directly using Sockets ?

Answer (score 1):

Will it work no matter where the two devices are and what are their IP addresses ?

**It should, even if you are on a private network, as long as you have your port forwards set correctly on each internal route.**

Does Android allow for incoming connection if i make it a Server ?

**It should**

Is it a good idea to connect two phones directly using Sockets ?

**I don't see why not**

Give it a try!  You might see some issues with your ISP or carrier only allowing certain ports through, try 80, 443, or 22 if higher port numbers are giving you problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect two Android devices using Sockets but as you want to connect them on WIFI and over WIFI you **won't have a static IP address** and this will create a problem for you if in any case **IP address of server is changed.**
Another problem is that if your Android server has a **private IP address** then you will not be able to connect to android server. I am not sure but i assume **every Android has a private IP address**